# How to reference a spring form input placeholder attribute value to a message source property?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-form, spring-messaging

Is it possible to retrieve a message from a `.properties` message-file using `spring:message` tag (spring tag library) within a spring-`form:input` tag (spring form tag library, used for data-binding).

---

**src/main/resources** > texts.properties (file)

```
testEntry=Test entry
```

---

**src/main/webapp/WIN-INF/JSP** > test.jsp

If I try to do it this way:

```html
<%@taglib prefix='spring' uri='http://www.springframework.org/tags'%>
<%@taglib prefix='form' uri='http://www.springframework.org/tags/form'%>

<form:input path="test" placeholder='<spring:message code="testEntry">'/>
```

I get as a result `<spring:message code="testEntry">` as a placeholder instead of `Test entry`

---

And if I try to do it this way:

```html
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix='spring' uri='http://www.springframework.org/tags'%>
<%@taglib prefix='form' uri='http://www.springframework.org/tags/form'%>

<c:set var="placeholder" value='<spring:message code="testEntry">'/>
<form:input path="test" placeholder='${placeholder}'/>
```

---

I get the same result. I understand the problem. But is there another way to do it within a JSP so that the message with the appropriate code appears as an attribute value of a spring-form tag?

Comment: `<spring:message code="testEntry" var="placeholder" />` then `<form:input path="test" placeholder='${placeholder}'/>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `var` attribute of the `message` tag to assign the resolved message to a named variable. You can then use that variable as an EL variable.

```
<spring:message code="testEntry" var="placeholder" />
<form:input path="test" placeholder='${placeholder}'/>
```

This assigns the resolved message for `testEntry` to a variable named `placeholder` which you can then use in the input tag.